# How to have FilterExpression with multiple conditions in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to do table scan on dynamodb 
Below is the code which is in javascript

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'Contacts',
    FilterExpression: 'begins_with(CustomerName,:value)OR begins_with(CustomerName,:val) ', 
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
        ':value': {'S':'S'},
        ':val':{'S':'E'},
      },
    Select: 'ALL_ATTRIBUTES', 
 };

 dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

But I couldn't try the same using botot3.

Below is what I could achieve so far

```
response = table.scan(
                  Select= 'ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
                  FilterExpression=Attr('CustomerName').begins_with("S") 
                  )
```

I couldn't understand how to add the OR condition. If I add, it shows error

Answer (score 53):

For  AND  '&' is used and for OR '|' is used

```
  response = table.scan(
              Select= 'ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
              FilterExpression=Attr('CustomerName').begins_with("S") | Attr('CustomerName').begins_with("S") 
              )
```

Comment: @Joe I don't remember the exact documentation Maybe this one can help you i guess http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.scan

Comment: @JoeCabezas Here you can find a reference to the operators in the official docs: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#querying-and-scanning


_"You are also able to chain conditions together using the logical operators: & (and), | (or), and ~ (not). For example, this scans for all users whose first_name starts with J and whose account_type is super_user:"_

Answer (score 1):

You can create a string compare= ["a = b", "c begins_with val'] and then join them with ' and '.join(compare)

creating for you the filter expression 'a = b and c begins_with val'

Comment: can you explain that more plz?